# UpdatePanelAnimationExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, updatepanelanimationexte

I have a search button and a grid view control which is inside the update panel!! i am using updatepanelanimationextender to fadeout all the control when the search is happening and show a progress bar at the middle,

Everything works fine when i click search button first time...How ever when i click the search button second time the progress bar loads continously and dont give any results, i have to refresh page and do all over again!!.

I am attaching the code here

Also on button search click i am calling a _dopostback() function !!

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks
.

Comment: You forgot to attach the code!